# How do I start services that use session D-Bus?

Tags: systemd, d-bus

I've written several programs that use D-Bus to communicate across a user session (i.e., not the system session).  This all works great when using my development system, but now I want to have these programs start up automatically on a headless server.

I read a couple resources (including the dbus-daemon man page) and https://github.com/ahkok/user-session-units but I've been unsuccessful so far and feel like I'm bashing my against the wall at this point.

Does anyone know how to get different services all on the same D-Bus session bus?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/892465/starting-systemd-services-sharing-a-session-d-bus-on-headless-system